# Why am I getting Error: identifier expected

Tags: java

My code is as follows. This is a school project and I am required to do this without using `else` statements. I don't understand why I'm getting errors including:

```
Main.java:16: error: ';' expected
    public static boolean isLeapYear( int testYear )
                                                    ^
Main.java:22: error: illegal start of type
                if(isLeapYear == false)
                ^
Main.java:22: error: <identifier> expected
                if(isLeapYear == false)
                             ^
```

Code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 

        //do not change any of the next 3 lines 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a year :: ");
        int year = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (isLeapYear == true) {
            return isLeapYear + " is a leap year";
        }
        if (isLeapYear == false) {
            return isLeapYear + " is not a leap year";
        }

    }
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int testYear)
    {
        //you will use the % operation to determine if  
        //testYear is a leap year. 

        int year = testYear;
        boolean isLeapYear = false;

        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            isLeapYear = true;
        }
        if (year % 4 != 0) {
            isLeapYear = false;
        }

        return isLeapYear;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another thing to note is that you are trying to return from a void method. Instead of returning you will want to do a System.out.println to print the result to the command line.

Comment: I think you should study [the basics of Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). You'll also learn about scopes and returning from methods.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a variable called `isLeapYear` in your `main`. I also suspect you want to call your method with the name `isLeapYear`, but you never do so.

Solve both issues at once by changing your main, add the following line after you read the user input:

```
boolean isLeapYear = isLeapYear(year);
```

Comment: thanks! sorry, what do you mean by "Solve both issues at once by changing your main, add the following line after you read the user input:"?

Comment: I think i was very precise with my recommendation. Are you familiar with the basics of java? Do you know where your code reads the user input?